# Sencha Touch 2.3 - don't do anything until location obtained

Tags: extjs, cordova, touch

I'm new to Sencha Touch and looking for some advice. I'm building an app which relies on the users location being obtained via Phonegap before doing things such as calling two separate REST API's which then populate two Lists.

As everything in this framework is pretty much asynchronous, what would be the best practice way of doing this? I don't want the app to let the user do anything unless we have a fix on the latitude/longitude of the device. e.g.

1) App starts

2) Query location

3) Wait for location

4) If successful lat/long returned then load store 1, load store 2, draw map and let user use app

Any thoughts much appreciated,

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using phonegap. User interactions happens after loading your first view from the app.js, launch() method. So, instead of loading the view right away, load it after you finish doing everything you need to do.

Phonegap API will be ready ondevice ready.

#### In your `app.js` launch()

`document.addEventListener("deviceready", yourCallbackFunction, false);`

Wait for the callback, then proceed to getting the location,

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);`

When you finish everything, then load your view

`Ext.create('ReShare.view.MainView', {fullscreen: true});`

References:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/master/doc/index.md

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. Yes using Phonegap. Your answer has helped. Part of the issue was that Sencha Architect sets a default view which always loads first. Turning this off and then creating the view manually has certainly helped.

Comment: However I'm still a little puzzled how I can load two stores via ajax and wait for them both to be loaded before initialising my view ?

Comment: This post helped me http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?276849-Best-Practice-for-Waiting-n-stores-to-load-before-showing-view

Comment: The forum post seems to be on the right track. But I'm just wondering if using autoLoad isn't good enough for your requirements?

Comment: Also, my two cents about architect: when I first started with sencha touch, architect was a godsend for learning, however, the restrictions on it proved to be a nuisance in disguise (for example, unable to fully edit files, difficult for collaborations, etc).

Comment: I can't use autoLoad because I need to wait for long/lat from geolocation and then define a custom URL for my store before loading it, but the method on the forum has worked well for me. I agree about Architect, I find it quite good as I am new to the framework but I find myself mostly editing the code directly - Architect just lets me quickly structure things and see everything from a top level. :-)